# how to create a custom cast explicit in c #?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

Have this code:

```
string abc = "123456";
```

To convert to int should I use convert:

```
int abcInt = Convert.ToInt32(abc);
```

The problem is that if not a number I have an exception see returning zero so my final code will look like:

```
try{ int abcInt = Convert.ToInt32(abc); }catch(Exception e){ int abcInt = 0; }
```

So you see that I decided to create a book that made ​​me an object returning zero numeric without exception if it failed, so could keep most flexible programming without much junk code:

```
int abcInt = Libs.str.safeInt(abc);
```

The code is:

```
public int safeInt(object ob)
{
    if ((ob == null) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ob.ToString())))
        return 0;
    try
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(ob.ToString(), @"@[^Ee0-9\.\,]+@i", "").
            ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat)
        );
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But I want to go one step further and do something like this:

```
int abcInt = (safeInt)abc;
```

how to do?

> Can not convert type 'string' to 'Libs.safeInt.safeInt'

Comment: int parsed = 0;
Int32.TryParse("demo", out parsed);

Comment: @sgud no need to initialize `parsed` to 0, it'll be set to a valid value or 0 anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *should* just use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx):

```
int abcInt;
if(!Int32.TryParse(abc, out abcInt)) {
    abcInt = 0;
}
// abcInt has been parsed to an int, or defaulted to zero
```

Note that this can be shortened to

```
int abcInt;
Int32.TryParse(abc, out abcInt);
```

if all that you want is the default value to be zero [because](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent to the number contained in `s`, if the conversion succeeded, or **zero if the conversion failed**. The conversion fails if the `s` parameter is `null`, is not of the correct format, or represents a number less than `MinValue` or greater than `MaxValue`. This parameter is passed uninitialized.

I actually recommend against writing it this way because now you can't distinguish between `abc = "0"` and `abc = "garbage"`; both with exhibit exactly the same behavior with the above two lines of code. With the initial version above (i.e., the `if`, you *can* distinguish the two cases if you need to; silently ignoring errors is *generally* a *bad* idea).

That said, if you *absolutely* are dying to know how to implement an [`explicit` cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx), you proceed like this:

```
class SafeInt32 {
    private readonly int value;
    public int Value { get { return this.value; } }

    private readonly string source;
    public string Source { get { return this.source; } }

    private readonly bool successful;
    public bool Successful { get { return this.successful; } }

    public SafeInt32(string source) {
        this.source = source;
        this.successful = Int32.TryParse(source, out this.value);
    }

    public static explicit operator SafeInt32(string source) {
        return new SafeInt32(source);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(SafeInt32 safeInt32) {
        return safeInt32.Value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int abcInt = (SafeInt32)"123456";
```

Note that we had to define an *explicit* cast operator to cast a `string` to a `SafeInt32`, and an [*implicit* cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) to cast a `SafeInt32` to an `int` to achieve your desired syntax. The latter is necessary so that the compiler can silently convert the result of `(SafeInt32)"123456"` to an `int`.

Again, I recommend *against* this; use `Int32.TryParse`.

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment. :)

Comment: @sgud: While that's correct, I present it this way for pedagogical purposes; it makes it clear the separation between the successful and non-successful cases. It turns out that `Int32.TryParse` already assigns to the result (in this case `abcInt`) the value zero if parsing fails. But again, doing it *this* way here is for clarity.

Comment: `out` always writes a value; you don't need to do anything depending on the return value, if a default of `0` is what you want. For clarity, though, I don't mind how you've got it here (plus makes it easier to change the default).

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage implicit and explicit operators to do what you want, yes.  You can also use `int.TryParse` to avoid using exceptions for control flow.

```
public struct SafeInt
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public static implicit operator int(SafeInt safeInt)
    {
        return safeInt.Value;
    }
    public static explicit operator SafeInt(string obj)
    {
        return new SafeInt() { Value = SafeParse(obj) };
    }
    public static int SafeParse(object value)
    {
        int output;
        int.TryParse((value ?? "0").ToString(), out output);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this too. "*User-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed.*"

Comment: @p.s.w.g Modified accordingly, to as close as you can get.

Comment: I'd recommend a constructor, `public SafeInt(object value)`. Then OP couldn't write `int i = new SafeInt(abc)` which I think is about as close as you can get to `int abcInt = (safeInt)abc;`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g The way I see it if the implicit conversion operator isn't an option (because the variable is typed as an object, not a string) the using the public static `SafeParse` method is probably the best bet.  I don't see it as being useful to use the constructor explicitly, which is why I made it private.  That certainly is an option though, if that's desirable.

Comment: "*Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors*", but I see your point. Personally I don't see much use in a code like this at all; data type conversions *should* be explicit, IMO. That little bit of extra code you have to write to do the conversion is just a reminder that you probably should probably rethink a weakly-typed design anyway.

Comment: Substitute `(value ?? "0").ToString()` with `"" + value`.

Comment: @ebyrob You could if you want; I prefer this.

Comment: @ebyrob or `string.Empty` to avoid the magic constant, or better yet, check for null first before you even call convert. Either way, it's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you should use `int.TryParse`, but if you're dead-set on the cast syntax:

```
public class SafeInt
{
    private int _value;
    private SafeInt() {}
    public static explicit operator SafeInt(string str)
    {
        int x;
        int.TryParse(str, out x);
        SafeInt si = new SafeInt();
        si._value = x;
        return si;
    }
    public static implicit operator int(SafeInt x)
    {
        return x._value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
int x = (SafeInt)"234234";
```

Comment: string safe = "Your UserID is: " + (SafeInt)UserId + "."; ... result: Your UserId is: Libs.SafeInt.SafeInt.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me just go on record saying that you may not want to do this.

Silently ignoring problems like this can cause other types of problems, such as a customer asking "Why is this total over here always wrong?".

Having said that, let's see how you can do what you want before I give you a better option:

```
void Main()
{
    int a = (SafeInt)"123";
    a.Dump();

    int b = (SafeInt)"xyz";
    b.Dump();
}

public struct SafeInt
{
    private readonly int _Value;

    public SafeInt(int value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    public SafeInt(int? value)
    {
        _Value = value ?? 0;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator int(SafeInt s)
    {
        return s.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator SafeInt(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            return new SafeInt(Convert.ToInt32(s));
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return new SafeInt();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out:

```
123
0
```

Now, my advice is to stay away from this. Instead, use this:

```
void Main()
{
    TryParse("123").Dump();
    TryParse("xyz").Dump();
}

public static int TryParse(string s, int errorValue = 0)
{
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out result))
        return result;
    return errorValue;
}
```

Note that if you always want 0 as the value to return upon an error, there's even a much simpler way built into the system, this:

```
int value;
int.TryParse("123", out value);
```

Here we disregard the Boolean result from `TryParse`, because if TryParse fails, *it'll set the parameter to 0*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you do not do this. I find explicit and implicit conversions to be hard to discover, read, and use, compared to simpler static methods and/or constructors.  Also, are you aware of the [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method? That might be a better solution for you:

```
public static int SafeInt(object value)
{
    int i;
    int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out i);
    return i;
}
```

Or, more directly to answer your question, you can use explicit and implicit conversions on a `SafeInt` class to do this:

```
public class SafeInt
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator int(SafeInt si)
    {
        return si.Value;
    }
    public static explicit operator SafeInt(String str)
    {
        return new SafeInt { Value = Libs.str.safeInt(str) };
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
int i = (SafeInt)"123";
```

Comment: Response.Write((SafeInt)"123"); write an string: "Libs.safeInt.safeInt". but: Response.Write((int)(SafeInt)"123"); works. need only safeInt without (int)

Comment: If you see a class name (e.g. "Libs.safeInt.safeInt") where you expected a nice string (e.g. "123"), that's usually because the default `ToString()` implementation on `Object` prints the object's type. You should override the `ToString()` method on `SafeInt` to return `Value.ToString()`.